# Use regular HTML input form instead of Bootstrap styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have 2 forms on 1 page. One form will be the Bootstrap styled form ([this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01E2T.png)), and the other will be the regular HTML form without any styling ([this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRxrI.png)).

If I try doing it right now, every time I use the input tag, it automatically uses Bootstrap's styling for the input. How can I "cancel" the styling so it uses the regular HTML styling?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. Just renamed a few dozen of the "input" classes from the top of the stylesheet to "input.styled", and used the following in the HTML:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input class="styled" style="width:300px" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the bootstrap styling for `<form>` and `<input>` in `bootstrap.css`, copy it into your own css class e.g `.bootstrap-form { /* css goes here */}` and then comment it out in the bootstrap file.

Then you can use the default form by just using;

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="firstname"><br />
<input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

And the bootstrap form by using;

```
<form class="bootstrap-form">
<input class="bootstrap-input" type="text" name="firstname"><br />
<input class="bootstrap-input" type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

Comment: What if I have an input-append form like this one? [http://i.imgur.com/rsQ7Sja.png](http://i.imgur.com/rsQ7Sja.png)

Comment: Then comment out the code for input like I said in my answer, and then use input-append as it is in the bootstrap examples.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing this for, but it might be easier to find the code you need within bootstrap and put that into your own css file. Doing this should give you a better understanding of css and how it works with html.

Comment: I understand how CSS works, it's just that there are 313 occurrences of "input" in the stylesheet.

Comment: Then you should be able to identify which ones are important for what you are trying to achieve. There will only be a handful.